# How to attach a file to Mailgun via command line?

Tags: bash, mailgun

There is nice example at [here](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#examples) that illustrates how to send an email from command line. My problem is I don't understand how attachment works. This is the sample code:

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
    -F from='Excited User <YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
    -F to='foo@example.com' \
    -F cc='bar@example.com' \
    -F bcc='baz@example.com' \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!' \
    --form-string html='<html>HTML version of the body</html>' \
    -F attachment=@files/cartman.jpg \
    -F attachment=@files/cartman.png
```

When I remove attachments I receive the message I sent. However I'm not able to receive it when I use attachment. So my questions is:

1. What is `@files`?
2. If I want to send an image from my desktop what should I pass to attachment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I just found it. `files` is fictional folder :)

You can just `cd` to desktop. Then add attachment like this:

```
-F attachment=@cartman.png
```

Thanks to this doc: http://blog.mailgun.com/mailgun-api-2-0-forget-mime/

Comment: This just caught me too! The doc would be better if they used a few different paths...

Comment: new url: https://www.mailgun.com/blog/mailgun-api-2-0-forget-mime/